# Need to push or setup rdp to and pc's to domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, rdp

I have about 8 PCs and I need to add them to the domain but I am out of the office for a few weeks. I would need to remote into these computers that I know. How can I RDP into a computer that is not on my domain though? I could have users download teamviewer or something but is there any programs I could use to push RDP to remote PCs?

I`m using Windows Server 2003. 
Is there some way I can do this if I know the computers' name or IP-address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Remote Desktop to logon to each computer using a local account (For example use `.\administrator` for the local administrator account). Then use the GUI to join the domain (right-click "Computer"...select "Properties"...click "Advanced system settings"...click "Computer Name" tab...click "Change"). The netdom command is useful, but may be a bit complicated for a novice.

Comment: ahh gotcha.. I have another question should I ask here or start a new one?

Answer (score 1):

You just connect directly to its name or IP address and log on with a local account.

Of course, if all you are doing is joining the computers to a domain, you could just skip the remote desktop junk and use [`netdom join`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772217%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: i`m sorry how do I do that.. I`m a noob haha thANKS

Comment: Ahhh I do this from the server right?